# Integer declaration

Tags: apex, class, sharing, visualforce

I have below method in a public with sharing class. In the method, I need to use an integer but unable to declare that. Can someone please help me in integer declaration here?

Snippet:

```
public with sharing class GMAProfileCon_SN {

  public void Add()
    {   
        count = count+1;
        //addMore();      
    }
```

Comment: please go thru the apex reference for data types which has all the details https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
public with sharing class GMAProfileCon_SN {

    private Integer count;

    public GMAProfileCon_SN(){
        this.count = 0;
    }
    public void Add()
    {   
        this.count = this.count+1;
        //addMore();
    }
}
```